# Is there a wordplay on "bear-skin" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, ambiguity

I have some trouble understanding the part in bold in the following passage from Daniel Defoe's *Anatomy of Exchange-Alley*, I would be unable to rephrase it.

> In a Word, having accepted them for Fifty Thousand Pounds more than he is able to pay, the Jobber has got an Estate, the Broker 2 or 300 Guineas, and the Esquire remains at Leisure to sell his Coach and Horses, his fine Seat and rich Furniture, **to make good the Deficiency of his Bear-Skins, and at last, when all will not go through it, he must give them a Brush for the rest**.

The complete book is here (see p. 5-6) : https://books.google.fr/books?id=M15jAAAAcAAJ

My feeling is that the author plays on "bear-skins" multiple meanings.

In OED we can indeed read:

> II. 8. Stock Exchange. A speculator for a fall; i.e. one who sells
>   stock for delivery at a future date, in the expectation that meanwhile
>   prices will fall, and he will be able to buy in at a lower rate what
>   he has contracted to deliver at a higher. Formerly, The stock so
>   contracted to be delivered, in the phrase 'to buy' or 'sell the bear;'
>   ... [As applied to stock thus sold, bear appears early in 18th c., and
>   was common at the time of the South Sea Bubble. The term 'bearskin
>   jobber,' then applied to the dealer now called the 'bear,' makes it
>   probable that the original phrase was `sell the bearskin,' and that it
>   originated in the well-known proverb, 'to sell the bear's skin before
>   one has caught the bear.' ...]

But I may overinterpret the text, which could explain my confusion.

Comment: In that context your interpretation -- that it refers to a problem with "short selling" -- is likely correct.  In other contexts Defoe might have referred to the actual skin of a bear (they were sold by hunters, etc), but the context doesn't fit that.

Comment: "Give them a brush for the rest" could mean a **brush-off** when there is still not enough money raised from the sales to pay off the debt.